# JPA Criteria api using IN expression with join

Tags: jpa, join, criteria-api

i have entity `Request` that have `@ManyToMany Set<Region> regions`, and `Region` entity have field `region` of type `RegionEnum` of enum type with constants of regions.
I need to create criteria to get requests, where its regions are in collection of RegionEnum;
In my choice:

```
List<RegionEnum> regs=...; // from method parameter
CriteriaBuilder cb=em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Request> cq=cb.createQuery(Request.class);

Root<Request> from=cq.from(Request.class);
cq.where(cb.isTrue(from.join("regions").get("region").in(regs)));
return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

I have an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PREDICATE_PASSED_TO_EVALUATION (There is no English translation for this message.)`

enum:

```
public enum RegionEnum {
CENTRAL("Центральный"),
SOUTH("Южный"),
NWEST("Северо-Западный"),
FEAST("Дальневосточный"),
SIB("Сибирский"),
URFO("Уральский"),
VOLGA("Волжский"),
NCAU("Северо-Кавказский");


private final String value;

private Region(String value) {
    this.value=value;
}

public String value() {
    return this.value;
}

}
```

is my criteria right and problem with enum? or criteria is bad?

Comment: In your first code fragment you did not show what the "regs" variable is.

Comment: I've added regs to question; I also tried to create array of predicates `cb.equal(from.join("regions").get("region"),r)`  ; where r is from `for(RegionEnum r:regs)` ,  but I have an ClassCastException that shows that it couldn't cast String to RegionEnum and I think the problem maybe in enum and it's comparing or somthing, is there links that shows IN expression Implementation?

Comment: from prev comment: ClassCastException shows on line  `for(RegionEnum r:regs)` and I don't understand why String? there are Region in the list regs

Comment: You are joining using from.join("regions").get("region")(...), but your region enum does not have a property named region. I can not verify this at this time, but could you try to use 'join("regions").in(regs)' and let me know what happens?

Comment: The `regions` field is `Set<Region>`  where `Region` is not enum but of entity class which has enum field `region`; it maybe intricately and I'll change it later; I fixed the problem - from jsf selectManyCheckbox, selected items were written to List<RegionEnum> as Strings and they then in criteria could not be converted to RegionEnum type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced with the same exception today so I tried to solve the problem.

Let's assume we have the following instances already initialized (as in your example):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb;
List<String> values;
Root<Entity> r; // where Entity has String name attribute
```

Now we can create a Predicate instance **this way which is working** using EclipseLink 2.6.2 library:

```
Predicate good = r.get("name").in(values);
```

**But if we try to wrap the predicate into the *cb.isTrue()* method** (as you did it) which require an "Expression<Boolean>" parameter like this:

```
Predicate wrong = cb.isTrue(r.get("name").in(values));
```

the mentioned exception **PREDICATE_PASSED_TO_EVALUATION** will be raised as you have received it even the expression has right syntax.

I think because Expression is an Ancestor of Predicate class but this just an idea. At least the exception message says something like this.

So **just remove the *cb.isTrue()* wrapping** and probably it will work for you as it works for me.